# How to properly filter multiple columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am using this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database.

I would like to filter the dataframe based on whether the rows contain any zero (except for `Outcome`).

When I try to filter the dataframe based on one column, everything is great:

[image: filtering by one column]

However, when I try to filter two or more columns I get different number of rows depending on whether I do like this:

[image: trying to filter by multiple columns]

or this:

[image: trying to filter by multiple columns]

with me getting 429 rows and 652 rows respectively.

So I tried filtering with `iloc`:

[image: filtering with iloc]

but that just fills the columns with NaN but doesn't remove the rows. Also it alters the `Outcome` column, which I want to keep intact. Seems like this `iloc` method only works when filtering one column at a time.

Is there some way how to filter the 8 columns at once instead of just doing one at a time?

Comment: The first of your attempts to do multiple columns (`data[(data.Pregnancies & data.Glucose) != 0]`) is wrong. The second one is right. That's why the results are different.

Comment: Provide data as text not images.

Comment: @user17242583 Thank you, this method worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to filter all columns at once, check-in each if a value is `0`, and return true if any.

```
result = df.drop(["Outcome"], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x != 0 , axis=0).any(1)
df[result]
```

Alternative solution without using apply:

```
# determine for each value cell whether it it zero
matches = df.drop(["Outcome"], axis=1) == 0

# build rowsums. It counts the number of zero values.
# if there are no zero values in a row, the rowsum is 0
# find all rows with a rowsum of 0
relevant_rows = matches.sum(axis=1) == 0

# subset just those rows with rowsum == 0
df.loc[relevant_rows, :]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method did not work as some collumns still contained zero values

Comment: Sorry, I understood 'on whether the rows contain any zero' as they SHOULD contain zeros. I updated the answer so that you exclude all rows that contain at least one `0`. Might you try to confirm this

Comment: I did try the new answer and it still produces collumns with zeros and the dataframe has the same amount of rows as before, so no rows were deleted. In the end I decided to do that manually by typing out all of that (df["Pregnancies"] != 0) & ...... , but i still wonder whether there is a better method

Comment: I added another approach that should also be more efficient than `apply`.

Comment: Thanks! The alternative solution worked perfectly. Could you please elaborate on what that code is actually doing? I have quite the trouble following

Comment: I added comments

Answer (score 2):

The first of your attempts to do multiple columns:

```
data[(data.Pregnancies & data.Glucose) != 0]
```

is wrong.

The second one:

```
data[(data.Pregnancies != 0) & (data.Glucose != 0)]
```

is right.

That's why the results are different.

Comment: Thank you, I used the second method and it worked.

Comment: Also, would you know why the first method isnt right and what is it actually doing?

Comment: Basically what you're doing with the first one, is you're creating a new Series object, where each value is zero if the corresponding values in either of the two series (`Pregnancies` and `Glucose`) are bitwise-ANDed...which it totally not what you're looking for.

Comment: In my case, **parenthesis** was the key!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
df[df.loc[:, 0:5] < 10].dropna(how='all', axis=1).dropna()
```

What that does, is it first creates a mask selecting all values of the first 5 columns that are less than 10. Then, it selects all the values from the dataframe selected by that mask.

Because the mask doesn't select all the columns, indexing the dataframe with that mask will return the columns that weren't accounted for by that mask (columns 6 onwards) as pure NaN values.  `.dropna(how='all', axis=1)` will drop all columns that are all NaN.

Finally, `.dropna()` will remove all rows that contain any NaNs, leaving you with all rows where all values match the condition (are less than 10).